# Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, admob

I know it could look like This Question but I could not fix it with the solution proposed and I could not comment on it too. The Error is : After add

> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'

I face this **error**.

> Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```